# Trying to show FullPhotoURL on a visualforce table

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, class, table

On our org we're capturing a referral person (Referral_Person_Opp__c) on the Opportunity Object - this field is a look up on the User Object.

I have created a simple table to show the top 5 referral persons for the month with the summed Amount of Opportunities Closed Won.

I am trying to display the profile photo of these users, I understand this field is called FullPhotoURL on the User Object. However I am unable to Group By this field. Please see my code below:

**Controller Class**

```
public class OpportunityController {
    public List<AggregateResult> topReferralPersons { get; set; }
    
    public OpportunityController() {
        topReferralPersons = [SELECT Referral_Person_Opp__r.Name referralName, SUM(Amount) totalAmount
                             FROM Opportunity
                             WHERE StageName = 'Closed Won'
                             AND CloseDate = THIS_MONTH
                             GROUP BY Referral_Person_Opp__r.Name 
                             ORDER BY SUM(Amount) DESC
                             LIMIT 5];
    }
                        }
```

**VisualForce Page**

```
<apex:page controller="OpportunityController">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Top Referral Persons">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!topReferralPersons}" var="result">
            <apex:column headerValue="Referral Name">
                <apex:outputText value="{!result['referralName']}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Total Amount">
                <apex:outputText value="{!result['totalAmount']}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Has anyone any suggestions on how I can implement the profile pictures? Thanks in advance